# where condition is met, get last row pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

```
+------------+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+-----+
|     WS     | 1  | 2  | 3  |  4  | 1  | 2  | 3  |  4  |
+------------+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+-----+
| w1         |  0 |  0 |  0 |  50 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  50 |
| w2         |  0 | 30 |  0 |   0 |  0 | 30 |  0 |   0 |
| d1         |  0 |  0 |  0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   0 |
| d2         | 62 |  0 |  0 |   0 | 62 |  0 |  0 |   0 |
| Total      | 62 | 30 |  0 |  50 | 62 | 30 |  0 |  50 |
| Cumulative | 62 | 92 | 92 | 142 | 62 | 92 | 92 | 142 |
+------------+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+-----+
```

Based on the condition of the column having value more than 0, I would like to get the corresponding value of row "Cumulative".

As shown in the image, when 50 > 0, I would like to get the corresponding "Cumulative" value of 142.

```
+------------+----+----+---+-----+----+----+---+-----+
|     WS     | 1  | 2  | 3 |  4  | 1  | 2  | 3 |  4  |
+------------+----+----+---+-----+----+----+---+-----+
| Cumulative | 62 | 92 | 0 | 142 | 62 | 92 | 0 | 142 |
+------------+----+----+---+-----+----+----+---+-----+
```

I have tried pandas loc and iloc but they cannot perform what I wanted.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Post your dataframe as text, not as an image.

Comment: Some code would be good, too.

Comment: Hope the problem description is better now.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should have designed your question better, but anyway, here is a possible solution:

Assuming **df** is your DataFrame:

```
df[df>5].loc['Cumulative'].dropna()
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Perhaps my edited problem description is clearer.